# DNS Timestamps don't appear to be updating since enabling Secure Only Updates

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic-dns, timestamp

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory Domain. There are 4 domain controllers each running DNS with a Active Directory-Integrated zone. There are 2 member servers running DHCP with Name Protection enabled. Dynamic updates in DNS are enabled and we have been allowing secure and unsecure updates in all the zones. Scavenging is also enabled; the No-refresh and Refresh intervals are both 3 days.

Yesterday at 11:00 AM we configured DNS to only allow secure updates in all the zones. Today when I checked DNS is found that looks like no time stamps are being refreshed. The latest time stamp is 9:00 AM yesterday, about 2 hours before we made the change to only require secure updates. I understand that anything with a time stamp less than 3 days old (the length of the No-refresh time) isn't going to be refreshed but there are a few servers with a timestamp of 2/15/14 8:00 PM. Shouldn't they have updated by now?

Comment: I figured out what was happening. I thought when I sorted the list it was refreshed. Apparently this is not correct. When I explicitly refreshed the list the new timestamps were displayed.